# Proving uniform continuity of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

Lets take the infinite sequence of functions
$f_{n}(x) = x/(x +1/n) , x \in [0, 1], n \in \Bbb N$.
Show that each function $f_{n}$ is uniformly continuous.

My solution:

Given $\epsilon >0$, let $x, y$ be such that $|x-y|<\delta$. Then,
$$ |f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)|=\bigg| \frac{x}{x+(1/n)}-\frac{y}{y+(1/n)}\bigg|=\bigg |\frac{x-y}{n[x+(1/n)][y+(1/n)]}\bigg| \leq (x-y)n$$

Choose $n<\epsilon/\delta$, then

$|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)|<\epsilon$. Hence proved.

Is this proof correct, please rectify if any flaw is there. Else suggest a different proof.

Comment: It looks good, except that you should get $|x-y|$ instead of $(x-y)$ at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine except the $(x-y)$ should be $|x-y|$.

Here is a shorter version:
You have $f_n'(x) = {n \over (nx+1)^2}$, and $|f_n'(x)| \le n$, hence the
mean value theorem shows that $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \le n |x-y|$.